# JavaFX TreeTableView and ContextMenu

Tags: javafx, contextmenu, fxml, treetableview

In my project I have a TreeTableView with 5 columns.
I need a different context Menu for every columns.
I have created a ContextMenu in Source Builder for every columns (in the example you see only one for "value" column), but the menù appears only with right click on column header, but I need the menù appears only on right click on cell value

```
      <TreeTableView fx:id="valueTable" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <columns>
      <TreeTableColumn fx:id="context" prefWidth="483.20001524686813" sortable="false" text="Context" />
      <TreeTableColumn fx:id="tag" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="90.0" sortable="false" text="Tag" />
      <TreeTableColumn fx:id="offset" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="90.0" sortable="false" text="OffSet" />
      <TreeTableColumn fx:id="lenght" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="90.0" sortable="false" text="Lenght" />
      <TreeTableColumn fx:id="value" prefWidth="367.99993896484375" sortable="false" text="Value">
           <contextMenu>
              <ContextMenu fx:id="contextMenuValue" >
                <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 1" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 2" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 3" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Action 4" />
                </items>
              </ContextMenu>
           </contextMenu>
      </TreeTableColumn>
    </columns>
  </TreeTableView>
```

I try to add this code for check the MouseClick event, but event is intercepted only on TreeTableView "valueTable" and not on TreeTableColumn "value".

```
        value.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (MouseEvent e) -> {
                System.out.println("Work Cell");
        });
        valueTable.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (MouseEvent e) -> {
            System.out.println("Work Table");
        });
```

Can you help me?
Regard.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by implementing a custom `TreeTableCell` then add the `ContextMenu` to the cell instead of the column like:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TreeTableView<MyModel> table;
    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<MyModel, String> first;
    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<MyModel, Boolean> second;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        first.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().getValue().nameProperty());
        first.setCellFactory(cell -> new MyCell());
        second.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().getValue().selectedProperty());

        MyModel john = new MyModel("John");
        MyModel andrew = new MyModel("Andrew");

        table.setRoot(new TreeItem<>());
        table.setShowRoot(false);
        table.getRoot().getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(john));
        table.getRoot().getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(andrew));

    }

    private class MyModel {

        private StringProperty name;
        private BooleanProperty selected;

        MyModel(String name) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        }

        StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
            return selected;
        }
    }

    private class MyMenu extends ContextMenu {
        MyMenu() {
            getItems().add(new MenuItem("Test"));
            getItems().add(new MenuItem("Item"));

        }
    }

    private class MyCell extends TreeTableCell<MyModel, String> {
        MyCell() {
            // Here you can set the same menu for each cell. Then the column is having the same cell for every row
            setContextMenu(new MyMenu());
        }

        // Overridden just to show the text of the cell.
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                contextMenuProperty().bind(Bindings
                    // here you can define your own condition
                    .when(getTreeTableRow().getTreeItem().getValue().selectedProperty())
                    .then(new MyMenu())
                    .otherwise((MyMenu) null));
                setText(item);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Of course you can set a different menu for the second column same as it is set for the first one.

Comment: unrelated to the problem/solution: "don't extend without adding functionality" == no need for a sub of ContextMenu, instead configure it by adding MenuItems

Comment: Yes you're right, I just extended if he wants to customize it, but as you mentioned it is useless to extend if you are using just this way as I did.

Comment: Thanks, work.
But remain the question: how to intercept the mouse click on TreeItem?
I need to intercept this to disable/enable Menu Item based on cell value.

Comment: I have edited my answer, by adding the condition in the `updateItem`, you can check it if this is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved with

```
            value.setCellFactory(tc -> {
            TreeTableCell<MyModel, String> cell = new TreeTableCell<MyModel, String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
                    setText(empty ? null : item);
                }
            };
            cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                if (! cell.isEmpty()) {
                    String userId = cell.getItem();
                    System.out.println("Work!");
                }
            });
            return cell ;
        });
```